# The onMouseLeave function is not called correctly

Tags: reactjs

The MouseLeave-function is called when I enter the svg-path with the mouse but not when leave it. The MouseEnter-funtion is called correctly. What is wrong?

```
 return (
          <path
          onMouseEnter={_this.onMouseEnter.bind(this, d)}
          onMouseLeave={_this.onMouseLeave()}/>
   )
```

Comment: also you can try out `onMouseOut` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `_this.onMouseLeave`. Just do the same you did for `_this.onMouseEnter`:

```
return (
  <path
    onMouseEnter={_this.onMouseEnter.bind(this, d)}
    onMouseLeave={_this.onMouseLeave.bind(this, d)}/>
)
```